# Find smallest int (path size) in recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm trying to find the smallest path size in a maze that uses recursion. 
To do this, the maze has to go through all the possible paths and then keep updating the "shortest length".

I was able to have it go through all the possible lists and print these coordinates and the path size, but I'm unable to find the minimum of values, as the path last found is always updated to be the "shortest length".

So, I was thinking of adding all of the solution path lengths to an `ArrayList<Integer> list`, and then create a separate static class outside of the recursion solve method, where I find the minimum and return it's value to the `solve()` method and proceed from there. Is this the most optimum way to do this? Or can I find the shortest length and corresponding coordinates in the `solve()` method?

This is what code for the recursive case:

```
else {
  for(int i = 0; i < directions.length; i++)
  {   
    Coord nextSpot = currentSpot.addTo(directions[i]); 
    if(nextSpot.validSpot(maze)) 
      if(!newPath.contains(nextSpot)){

      ArrayList<Coord> solution = //The recursive call
                         solve(newPath,nextSpot,goal,maze); 

        if(solution != null){ 

          int shortestLength = 100; //arbitrary large length
         // lengths.add(lengthSolution); ?? Possible alternative?
          System.out.println(lengthSolution);
          System.out.println(solution);
          if( solution.size() < shortestLength ){
            shortestLength = solution.size();
            System.out.println(shortestLength);
          } 
        }
    }//ifs
  }//for
   return null;
}//else (recursive case)
```

Comment: What's wrong with *Dijstra's algorithm*?

Comment: @CommuSoft I looked at tutorials of that, but I'm not sure I really understand how I would write code for that. Would that be the best way for this case?

Comment: @kat-Well if you're having problem implementing Dijkstra's algo,maybe once you should practice from the tutorial. `Commusoft` is write about his views on the solution to this problem. It has to be `Dijkstra's algorithm`!

Comment: Is there a way to find this smallest path size with the code that I have though?

Answer (score 0):

```
int globalsteps =0;

int maze(x,y,steps) {
    if(icangoup){  maze(x+1,y,steps +1);}
    if(icangodown){ maze(x-1,y,steps +1);}
    if(icangoleft){  maze(x,y+1,steps +1);}
    if(icangoright){  maze(x,y-1,steps +1);}
    if(ifoundtheexit!!!!) {
        if(globalsteps == 0 || steps < globalsteps)
            globalsteps = steps;
        }
    }
}
```